# Password generator not working

Tags: password-generator

I am a python noob and I don't know what's wrong with my code. Whenever I run it it just prints out "this is your password:     " with nothing after that when it is supposed to print out the generated password.

```
import random

strength = ['Weak', 'Medium', 'Strong']

charbank = ('1234567890qwertyuiopASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM')

chosenchars = ('')

choice = ('')

def inputfunction():
    while True:
        userchoice = input("Would you like your password to be: \n Weak \n Medium? \n Strong?\n")
        if userchoice in strength:
            choice = ''.join(userchoice)
            break
        print ('oops, that\'s not one of the options. Enter again...')
    return choice

def strengththing():
    if choice == ("Weak"):
        Weak()
    if choice == ("Medium"):
        Medium()
    if choice == ("Strong"):
        Strong()

def Weak():
    passlen = 5
    chosenchars.join(random.sample(charbank, passlen))

def Medium():
    passlen = 10
    chosenchars.join(random.sample(charbank, passlen))

def Strong():
    passlen = 15
    chosenchars.join(random.sample(charbank, passlen))



inputfunction()
strengththing()

print ('this is your password: %s' %chosenchars)
```

Any help would be great. I don't know where I went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this programming language, but I would suggest you try printing the password in each method, and see if the problem is there, at least that will give you a closer idea of where the problem is

Comment: And you are not a noob!

Comment: @Steven Haha thanks for the encouraging words, but my noobiness persists as I still cannot figure out what is wrong. Any other help out there?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't change the value of 'choice' with your return statement after your While loop.

I did a few modifications.

There you go :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

strength = ['Weak', 'Medium', 'Strong']
charbank = ('1234567890qwertyuiopASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM')
chosenchars = ('')
choice = ('')

def inputfunction():
    while True:
        userchoice = input("Would you like your password to be: \n Weak \n Medium? \n Strong?\n")
        if userchoice in strength:
            choice = ''.join(userchoice)
            break
        else:
            print ('oops, that\'s not one of the options. Enter again...')
    return choice

def strengththing():
    if choice == 'Weak':
        return RandomPass(5)
    if choice == 'Medium':
        return RandomPass(10)
    if choice == 'Strong':
        return RandomPass(15)

def RandomPass(passlen):
    myVar = ''.join(random.sample(charbank, passlen))
    return myVar

choice = inputfunction()
chosenchars = strengththing()

print ('this is your password: %s' %chosenchars)
```

Comment: Alright, thank you! This worked. I have a question though. How come you have to reassign choice and chosenchars at the bottom to the inputfunction() and strengththing()? Why couldn't you just call the functions since inputfunction() returns choice?

Comment: @R_C For what I understood, and I'm not a Python programmer but a Jave one, you were returning choice from your inputfunction which was supposed to set your global variable choice. For a reason that I ignore, this assignation did not work. That's why I ended up returning local variable from your 2 functions.